# YouTube movie length limit

Tags: youtube

While uploading a family video to YouTube, I've noticed the following message:

> Congratulations! Your account is now enabled for uploads longer than 15 minutes. Click the Upload button below to select a video.

It might be related to the fact that the accumulated view count of all my videos has just reached 5,000.

Do you have any idea what's the video length limit policy of YouTube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now officially 15 min but depending on when you created the account and its type, other rules can apply.

Source: http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71673

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't seem to apply to my account.

Comment: Yes, they seem to keep old rules for old accounts and migrate them to new rules once in a while. There does not seem to be a way to get the *historical* rules.